# Symfony - Guardar objeto con relacion ManyToOne

Tags: sql, symfony, symfony4, doctrine, dql

Estoy creando un objeto llamado **repuesto** que tiene una categoria denominada **tiporepuesto**. Pero cuando intento hacer un persist() y flush() me genera el siguiente error:

**A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\Repuesto#tipoRepuesto' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Entity\TipoRepuesto@0000000070316c2100000000334485d6. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"})**

Declare las dos entidades y defini las relaciones entre estas:

en *repuesto.php*  tengo lo siguiente:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\TipoRepuesto",inversedBy="repuestos")
 */
private $tipoRepuesto;
```

en *tiporespuesto.php* tengo definido

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Repuesto", mappedBy="tipoRepuesto")
 */
private $repuestos;
```

Intente usar cascade persist pero me agrega elementos en la tabla de TIPOREPUESTOS. La tabla ya tiene su contenido y lo que debo hacer es referenciar cada respuesto con una fila de dicha tabla.
Cualquier info es bienvenida
Gracias!!

Comment: Has hecho el persist en las dos entidades, antes de hacer un flush?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre que el error se debía no a una incorrecta definicion de las relaciones ManyToOne o OneToMany. Las cuales quedaron de la siguiente forma:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Repuesto", mappedBy="tipoRepuesto",cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $repuestos;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\TipoRepuesto", inversedBy="repuestos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $tipoRepuesto;
```

Las relaciones fueron generadas con el comando **php bin/console make:entity**

Sino a que habia declarado la variable $repuesto fuera del bucle. Ocasionando un efecto de pisado por asi decirlo de los datos y generando un efecto estraño. Dado que por ejemplo debía insertar 3 filas de repuesto y solo me insertaba 2.

Cambie mi code como estaba:

```
$repuesto = new Repuesto();
foreach($repuestos as $r){

        // hago todos los set necesarios

        $entityManager->persist($repuesto);
        $entityManager->flush();

    }
```

A la siguient forma, con la que se resolvio el problema

```
foreach($repuestos as $r){
        $repuesto = new Repuesto(); //creo mi variable objeto dentro del loop
        // hago todos los set necesarios

        // preparo y persisto
        $entityManager->persist($repuesto);
        $entityManager->flush();

    }
```